# Show that the Markov chain, with $p_{k,0}=a_k$ and $p_{k,k+1}=1-a_k$, is transient if $\sum_ka_k<\infty$

Tags: markov-chains, markov-process

I have the following problem

> let $\{a_k\}_{k\geq0}$ be a sequence of positive numbers and $\{X_k\}$ a Markov chain with the probabilities $p_{k,0}=a_k$ and $p_{k,k+1}=1-a_k$, $k=0,1,2...$ Show that the chain is transient if, and only if, $\sum_ka_k<\infty$

This chain is irreducible, as every state communicate with which other. So, to prove it's transient I just need to show that any state is transient. So I picked state $0$.
I also have the $j$ is transient if, and only if, $$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}P_{jj}^k<\infty$$
If $P_{00}^k=a_k$ it'd be perfect. So I tried to get $P_{00}^1,P_{00}^2,P_{00}^3$, but the calculations are really ugly. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Simply compute explicitely $$P_0(T_0=\infty)$$ in terms of $(a_k)$, the result is an infinite product and you will have to determine whether it converges or not.

Comment: Not interested? Too bad.

Comment: Sorry, but I'm still trying to compute it, but I don't get it. I'm stuck with a series

Comment: Here is what I got $P_0(T_0=\infty)=1-P_0(T_0<\infty)=1-\sum_kP_0(T_0=k)$. Then, $P_0(T_0=k)=(1-a_0)(1-a_1)...(1-a_{k-1})a_k$. I don't know how to compute this series. I must be doing something wrong.